enum float problem calculating price of coffee
package Main;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    List<Ingredients> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public enum Ingredients { 
        SUGAR(0.25), // these are the problem
        MILK(1.25), // this
        CREAM(1.75); // and this one
        
        private final float cost;

        Ingredients(int cost) {
            this.cost = cost;
        }

        public float getCost() {
            return cost;
        }
    }

    public enum Sizes {
        SMALL(5),
        MEDIUM(10),
        LARGE(15);
        
        private final int cost;

        Sizes(int cost) {
            this.cost = cost;
        }

        public int getCost() {
            return cost;
        }
    }

    public static float calculateCost(Sizes size, List<Ingredients> ingredients) {
        int totalCost = size.getCost();
        for (Ingredients ingredient : ingredients) {
            totalCost += ingredient.getCost();
        }
        return totalCost;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Ingredients> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
        ingredients.add(Ingredients.MILK);
        ingredients.add(Ingredients.SUGAR);
        System.out.println("Cost of a small size coffee with milk and suger: " + calculateCost(Sizes.SMALL, ingredients));
    }

i was expecting a float with the number
6.5

this was the output
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Main.Main$Ingredients.getCost()" because "ingredient" is null
    at Java/Main.Main.calculateCost(Main.java:44)
    at Java/Main.Main.main(Main.java:53)

it says that this is a problem
totalCost += ingredient.getCost();

but is was not a problem earlier until i made the enum ingredients a float
i am fairly new to coding in java so i don't really know much about enums so i might learn more about them later

You have a class member named ingredients and a local variable in main with the same name. You put valid data into the latter, then call calculateCost which tries to extract data from the former which has never been set to anything and is thus null.

moreover, you have a float/double to int convertion issue.

for sure that is not the code that is throwing the NullPointerException: 1)  SUGAR(0.25) has a double, but the constructor Ingredients(int cost) requires an int; 2) there is no NullPointer in posted code.

@dave_thompson_085 - not the problem in posted code (unless it was changed [in the first 5 Minutes])- you forgot the parameter of the calculateCost method, also called ingredients, which is indeed receiving the correct data. Even if that was not the case, an empty list would not cause a NullPointerException

Here are the corrected types.  I recommend you change the cost of the Sizes enum to double too for flexibility.
And you can use NumberFormat to format the output in a form of currency.  Currency type and decimal separator depends on Locale."
public class CoffeOrder {

   
        List<Ingredients> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
        
        public enum Ingredients { 
            SUGAR(0.25), // these are the problem
            MILK(1.25), // this
            CREAM(1.75); // and this one
            
            private final double cost;

            Ingredients(double cost) {
                this.cost = cost;
            }

            public double getCost() {
                return cost;
            }
        }

        public enum Sizes {
            SMALL(5),
            MEDIUM(10),
            LARGE(15);
            
            private final double cost;

            Sizes(double cost) {
                this.cost = cost;
            }

            public double getCost() {
                return cost;
            }
        }

        public static double calculateCost(Sizes size, List<Ingredients> ingredients) {
            double totalCost = size.getCost();
            for (Ingredients ingredient : ingredients) {
                totalCost += ingredient.getCost();
            }
            return totalCost;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            List<Ingredients> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
            ingredients.add(Ingredients.MILK);
            ingredients.add(Ingredients.SUGAR);
            NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
            double cost = calculateCost(Sizes.SMALL, ingredients);
            System.out.printf("Cost of a small size coffee with milk and suger: %s%n",currency.format(cost));
                    

}

prints
Cost of a small size coffee with milk and sugar: $6.50

